# Get last day in month in AppleScript and holidays in current month

Tags: excel, applescript

I am writing an AppleScript which generates an MS Excel spreadsheet every month. I need to know how many days are in the current month, then go trough all months and decide if a given day is a weekday or a holiday.

I suppose I would save holidays (from this web http://kalendar365.cz/statni-svatky/2016 as table and access them locally) for this.

My question is:

1. How do I get the last day in a month?
2. How do I efficiently loop trough all days in the current month and decide if it is Sunday, Saturday or a day specified somewhere else (for example, in a text file of xlsx spreadsheet)?

Comment: In vanilla AppleScript you can get the last day of the current month this way: 1) set a variable to `current date` 2) Set the `day` property of that date to 32 to force an overflow. That sets the date to the first day of next month. 3) Subtract one day.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to let excel calculate that? There is a build in [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) function which would do all of that in one step...

Comment: @vadian: That's not how it works (at least on OS 10.8+): paste the following 3 statements into Script Editor and run them, and you'll see that the resulting date is March _3rd_, not March 1st (you may have to tweak the date string to match your locale): `set aDate to date "February 1, 2016"`, `set day of aDate to 32`, `aDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pbell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061870/45375) is promising, but the `GetLastDay` function doesn't work correctly for months that have fewer than 31 days; here's a function that fixes that:

```applescript
# Returns the number of days in the month that the given date falls in.
# Example:
#     my GetNumberOfDaysInMonth(current date)
on GetNumberOfDaysInMonth(aDate)
    local aDateCopy
    copy aDate to aDateCopy
    set day of aDateCopy to 1
    if month of aDateCopy is December then
        set year of aDateCopy to ((year of aDateCopy) + 1)
        set month of aDateCopy to 1
    else
        set month of aDateCopy to ((month of aDateCopy) + 1)
    end if
    return day of (aDateCopy - 1 * days)
end GetNumberOfDaysInMonth
```

The approach is based on setting the date to the 1st of the month, then incrementing the month (possibly rolling over into the next year), and subtracting 1 day, which works correctly with all dates, even in leap years.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple no-function-needed method?

```
set currdate to the current date
set nextmonth to currdate + (30 * days)
set {year:y, month:m, day:d, time:t} to nextmonth
set ms to m as string --month as string
set ys to y as string --year as string
set firstday to date (m & " 1," & y as string) --midnight at the first day of next month
set lastday to (firstday - 1) --minus one second
return lastday -- last day of the this month at 11:59 PM
```

As for weekends and holidays in Excel, doesn't Excel provide its own functions for that, as dirk-reichel mentioned?

However, if you want to use AppleScript to filter out these days using a pre-specified list of holidays, maybe this example will help. It loops through October through December of 2022, with USA holidays Halloween, Thanksgiving and Christmas Day specified. Note that Christmas Day happens to land on a Sunday in 2022.

```
set weekend to {"Saturday", "Sunday"}

set holidays to {date "October 31, 2022", date "November 24, 2022", date "December 25, 2022"}

set workdays to {}
set my_date to (date "Saturday, October 1, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM")
repeat
    set dy to the weekday of my_date
    set mydy to dy as string
    if weekend does not contain mydy and holidays does not contain my_date then
        set workdays to workdays & my_date
    end if
    set my_date to my_date + (1 * days)
    
    if my_date contains (date "January 1, 2023") then --specify an end date for your loop
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
return workdays
```

Answer (score -1):

The script below contains the 2 routines you're looking for : GetlastDay and isWorkingDay :

```
set myDate to current date -- just for example !

set N to GetlastDay(myDate)
log N --> number of days in month of myDate
set A to IsWorkingday(myDate)
log A --> true if Monday to Friday, false if Saturday/Sunday


on GetlastDay(LDate) -- return last day of month of LDate
copy LDate to L -- to not change LDate
set L's day to 32 -- = first day of next month
set L to L - (1 * days) -- last day of month
return day of L
end GetlastDay

on IsWorkingday(LDate) -- true if date is not Saturday or Sunday
set SD to weekday of LDate
return (SD is not in {Saturday, Sunday})
end IsWorkingday
```

Comment: Your `GetlastDay` function only works for months that have 31 days.